# AWS S3: command not found and cannot configure "testbucket" error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron

I am running file upload to AWS S3 python script using a cron job.
The result of the cron job is sent via mail to me.

Everything is working fine except the extra message that I'm getting in mail.
The error is `sh: aws: command not found`.

I tried setting the PATH environment variable in the script;

```
os.environ["PATH"] = "usr/bin:/usr/local/bin"
```

and I got rid of the error, but a new one showed up `The config profile (247-datapusher-s3) could not be found`

Just want to get rid of both of these messages.

## *Note:  *The script is working perfectly in both the cases and the files are successfully uploaded to AWS S3 bucket.*

Thanks in advance!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check your config file. Edit `~/.aws/config`

you will get something like

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY_PASS
region = us-east-1 (or another region)

[247-datapusher-s3]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY_PASS
region = us-east-1 (or another region)
```

you will need to change to

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY_PASS
region = us-east-1 (or another region)

[profile 247-datapusher-s3]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = KEY_PASS
region = us-east-1 (or another region)
```

If you do not even see the 247-datapusher-s3 section and you're using it, you will need to add in your config file.

Comment: I just edited the files and now it is as below...


[default]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_ID



[profile 247-datapusher-s3]
aws_access_key_id = KEY_ID
aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY_ID


Still I'm getting *The config profile (247-datapusher-s3) could not be found *